# Bezier Curve using FabricJS or HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent, fabricjs, bezier

I want to draw a bezier curve that connects two nodes. Want to implement it using mouse events in either HTML Canvas or FabricJS, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHreS.png

So far I have been able to implement this (given below), which draws the first curve, but when I try to draw the second curve, it erases the first one.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class CurveBoard extends Component{


  componentDidMount(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ac0000';

    let isDrawing = false;
    let startX, startY, x2, y2;
    let endX = 0;
    let endY = 0;
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
        isDrawing = true;
        [startX, startY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
    })

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        if(isDrawing){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            [endX, endY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY]
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20, 10, endX, endY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    })

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
        isDrawing = false;
    })

  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <canvas id="c" width="1000px" height="1000px"/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CurveBoard;
```

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/quadratic-curve

Comment: Try this: https://rete.js.org

Comment: Cool, but SO is not for "I want to do X", so: welcome but please take the [tour], make and make sure to read up on [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic) here, as well as (once you are certain your question is on topic) the policy article on [asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask). If you're still at "I want to do X", it's too soon to ask on SO: start trying some things first, and then when you've picked a library, and you've started writing code, and it doesn't work, _and_ doing your own debugging/searching first doesn't get you anywhere, that's when it's appropriate to post to SO.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am new to StackOverflow. But have now added the code that I have tried.

Comment: What do you mean with "when I try to draw the second curve"? Can you show the code that's going wrong, not just the code that's going right? (Because the code that works is not code that has a problem, and so implies there is no question to ask). And on a Bezier note: why draw two quadratic curves? Just draw a single cubic curve?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The code that's going wrong is the one given above. It is clearing the canvas when I try to draw the second curve. "Second Curve" means "another curve". I want to have as many curves as I want on my canvas.

Comment: Um.. of course? You know you have a `ctx.clearRect` there, right? You're _intentionally_ wiping the canvas on every single mouse move =D

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes. I am aware of the `ctx.clearRect` method. After some research, I found a solution on [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dTs4h/1/). But was hoping for some better, maybe efficient solution on SO.